# Why are my variables not recognized in R?

Tags: r

I'm quite a beginner in R. I wrote a script that worked just fine. However, since yesterday, it just doesn't recognize my variables anymore. I can view the dataset, but can't do any analysis.

```
tba_hba <- read_excel(k.file)
tba_hba

   AMT   E0    M     `X-Kto`    S1    S2    S3    S4 
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> 
 1 TBA   D0    T248~ X1.2.1~     1     2     1     0 
 2 TBA   D0    T248~ X1.2.1~     1     2     1     0 
 3 TBA   D0    T248~ X0.3.1~     0     3     1     0 
 4 TBA   D0    T248~ X0.3.1~     0     3     1     0 
 5 TBA   D0    T248~ X0.3.1~     0     3     1     0 
 6 TBA   D0    T248~ X0.3.1~     0     3     1     0 
 7 TBA   D0    T248~ X0.3.1~     0     3     1     0 
 8 TBA   D0    T248~ X0.3.1~     0     3     1     0 

count(tba_hba, S1)

Error in count(tba_hba, S1) : object 'S1' not found
```

I can see the variable S1, but can't do a count on it.

I get the same error when using read.xlsx.

Any ideas why this happens since yesterday without changing anything on my data?

EDIT: This are my data:

```
structure(list(AMT = c("TBA", "TBA", "TBA", "TBA", "TBA", "TBA", 
"TBA", "TBA", "TBA", "TBA", "TBA", "TBA", "TBA", "TBA", "TBA"
), E0 = c("D0", "D0", "D0", "D0", "D0", "D0", "D0", "D0", "D0", 
"D0", "D0", "D0", "D0", "D0", "D0"), M = c("T248A15", "T248A15", 
"T248A15", "T248A15", "T248A15", "T248A15", "T248A15", "T248A15", 
"T248A15", "T248A15", "T248A15", "T248A15", "T248A15", "T248A15", 
"T248A15"), S1 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0), S2 = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), S3 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), S4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Projekt = c("Y02.9.8.1", "Y02.9.8.1", 
"Y34.6.1.2", "Y01.6.1.1", "Y01.6.1.1", "Y05.6.1.1", "Y04.6.1.1", 
"Y04.6.1.1", "Y05.6.1.1", "Y21.9.8.1", "Y23.9.8.1", "Y05.6.1.1", 
"Y03.6.1.1", "Y03.6.1.1", "Y05.6.1.1")), row.names = c(NA, -15L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Try `count(tba_hba, tba_hba$S1)`. Based on the code you provided, it looks like you haven't assigned `k.file` a value. So before you read in your Excel file, you need to specify: `k.file <- "C:/filepath/file.xlsx"`

Comment: @Matt: 
count(tba_hba, tba_hba$S1)
Error: Can't subset with `[` using an object of class quoted.

This also doen't work.

`#jährlich anzupassende Jahreszahl`
`k.jahr = 2019`

`#dynamischer Dateiname`
`k.file = paste("Rohdaten-TBA-HBA-",k.jahr,"_orig.xlsx", sep="")`
`k.file`

`#Datei einlesen`
`setwd(file.path("P:/2_Statistikproduktion/SUBMISS/01 Bezogene Daten/Kreko",         k.jahr))`
`tba_hba <- read_excel(k.file)`
`tba_hba`

Comment: @Matt 
When doing it like you suggest, I then get the warning
`In read_fun(path = enc2native(normalizePath(path)), sheet_i = sheet,  ... :
  Coercing text to numeric in W1583 / R1583C23: '8590'`

Comment: Please provide your actual data with `dput(head(data))`.

Comment: `> ls()`
`[1] "k.file"  "tba_hba"`
`> str(tba_hba)`
`Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 15 obs. of  8 variables:`
`$ AMT    : chr  "TBA" "TBA" "TBA" "TBA" …`
 `$ E0     : chr  "D0" "D0" "D0" "D0" …`
 `$ M      : chr  "T248A15" "T248A15" "T248A15" "T248A15" …`
 `$ S1     : num  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 …`
 `$ S2     : num  2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 …`
 `$ S3     : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 …`
 `$ S4     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 …`
 `$ Projekt: chr  "Y02.9.8.1" "Y02.9.8.1" "Y34.6.1.2" "Y01.6.1.1" …`

Comment: your code works for me with the data you provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly guess you do not call the function you think you would. Try:

```
dplyr::count(df, S1)
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#       S1     n
#    <dbl> <int>
# 1     0    11
# 2     1     4


# The error message if a S_xy is not in the data:
dplyr::count(df, S_xy)
# Error: Column `S_xy` is unknown
```

Comment: Very good point! The original error message can be reproduced when confusing package *d*plyr and plyr:  `plyr::count(tba_hba, S1)`.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess was that something happened while reading the file from Excel. If one reads the data as written in your question, it should work:

```
library("dplyr")
library("readr")
x <- (
  "AMT   E0    M     `X-Kto`    S1    S2    S3    S4
TBA   D0    T248~ X1.2.1~     1     2     1     0
TBA   D0    T248~ X1.2.1~     1     2     1     0
TBA   D0    T248~ X0.3.1~     0     3     1     0
TBA   D0    T248~ X0.3.1~     0     3     1     0
TBA   D0    T248~ X0.3.1~     0     3     1     0
TBA   D0    T248~ X0.3.1~     0     3     1     0
TBA   D0    T248~ X0.3.1~     0     3     1     0
TBA   D0    T248~ X0.3.1~     0     3     1     0")

tba_hba <- read_delim(x, delim=" ", trim_ws = TRUE)
count(tba_hba, S1)
```

Option `trim_ws` is important here for the column names, but in `read_excel` this argument is `TRUE` by default.

Then @mnist came with the suggestion, that another function was used. Confusing plyr with **d**plyr is indeed a reasonable explanation.

Compare the following:

```
plyr::count(tba_hba, S1)
Error in count(tba_hba, S1) : object 'S1' not found
```

and:

```
dplyr::count(tba_hba, S1)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
     S1     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     0     6
2     1     2
```

To overcome this, check the order how the packages are loaded or, even better, use the `::`-syntax.

Comment: It was indeed the confusion of plyr and dplyr! It works now perfectly fine. I did not realize that this can have such an effect. Thank you very much.

Comment: Packages plyr and dplyr follow completely different approaches. The tidyverse-appraoch is very cool, but in contrast to the very conservative style of base R, Hadley Wickham follows a more dynamic approach and functionality changes. If you load both, plyr should come before dplyr, otherwise a warning is shown.

Answer (score 0):

you probably `attach(the.data.set)` then `rm(list=ls())` or `detach(the.data.set)` better not to use `attach()` and used `$`

```
table(tba_hba$S1)
```

Comment: `table`is ok, but please *never* use attach!